# How to perform a redirect after completing a Quiz?

Tags: 7, redirection, quiz

I am using [Quiz](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz) module. How can we redirect user to thankyou/someother page after clicking Finish button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## If using Quiz 7.x-5.x

Assuming you're using the [7.x-5.x-rc3 version](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz/releases/7.x-5.0-rc3) of the [Quiz](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz) module, you can take advantage of integration with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module that this new release comes with.

To do so, have a look at the [delivered rule](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/quiz/tree/quiz.rules_defaults.inc#n18), which looks like so:

```
{ "rules_send_results_at_the_end_of_a_quiz" : {
    "LABEL" : "Send quiz results at the end of a quiz",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "ACTIVE" : false,
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "quiz" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "entity" ],
    "ON" : { "quiz_result_update" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "quiz-result-unchanged:is-evaluated" ], "value" : "0" } },
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "quiz-result:is-evaluated" ], "value" : "1" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "mail" : {
          "to" : [ "quiz-result:uid:mail" ],
          "subject" : "[site:name]: Your results for [quiz-result:nid:title]",
          "message" : "[quiz-result:uid:name],\r\n\r\nYou finished the quiz [quiz-result:nid:title] on [quiz-result:time-start]\r\n\r\nYour score: [quiz-result:score]%\r\n\r\nYou can access the result here: [site:url]node\/[quiz-result:nid:nid]\/quiz-results\/[quiz-result:result-id]",
          "language" : [ "" ]
        }
      },
      { "mail" : {
          "to" : [ "quiz-result:nid:author:mail" ],
          "subject" : "[site:name]: [quiz-result:uid:name]\u0027s results for [quiz-result:nid:title]",
          "message" : "[quiz-result:nid:author:name],\r\n\r\n[quiz-result:uid:name] finished the quiz [quiz-result:nid:title] on [quiz-result:time-start]\r\n\r\nTheir score: [quiz-result:score]%\r\n\r\nYou can access the result here: [site:url]node\/[quiz-result:nid:nid]\/quiz\/results\/[quiz-result:result-id]\/view",
          "language" : [ "" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

After you enable [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) (and Rules UI, a submodule of it), just clone the above rule (using the Rules UI) and replace both Rules Actions with a basic "redirect" (a typical Rules Action) that fits your needs.

## If using Quiz 7.x-4.x

For the [7.x-4.x version](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz/releases/7.x-4.0-rc2) of the [Quiz](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz) module, you may want to try the [patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/quiz_rules_integration.patch) from [fago](https://www.drupal.org/u/fago) (aka the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) maestro ...), attached to [issue # 1300420](https://www.drupal.org/node/1300420), which has a description like so (note the last phrase in it ...):

> ... adds basic rules integration to quiz. It includes an event when users have finished taking a quiz, a condition to check whether a user has passed a certain quiz and an action to clear quiz results for a user.
>
> Patch works for me.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet @pierre, but I am using 7.x-4.0-beta2 version and I cant able to update that module due to some circumstances. Can I still use this?

Comment: @Nagarjuna : 2nd try ... see my updated answer ... curious if you can get that to work ...

Comment: i was busy with some other task. I will surely get back to u. Thanks for the answer.. Cheers

Comment: That works. I need to modify the rule condition, for now it is only passed, I need to make another one if is fail. I can manage though. Cheers :)